# React component's state change from constructor to componentDidMount is not effecting Render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have component like so:

```
class GettingStarted extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      measureCompletion: '0%',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      measureCompletion: '70%',
    });

  }

  render() {
      ...
      <div style={{width: this.state.measureCompletion}}></div>
     .....
```

This behavior correctly on first load, when the component loads, the width is set to 70% from 0% which causes a nice animation w this css:

```
      transition: width 1s cubic-bezier(0,0,.2,1) .5s;
```

The problem is, if I navigate to another component in my app and then back to this component, while constructor gets called, the div width is not being changed and not animating.

Why isn't the width value being re-rendered, causing the desired animation?

Comment: When you say "navigate away" do you mean that this component is fully unmounted by a parent or otherwise?

Comment: If you are sure that the constructor is called then componentDidMount will also be called and the state will change. Also if you navigate away can you make sure that you component is unmounted

Comment: @veratti click another <Link> in my app and then click back. I don't call unmount, didn't know I needed to do that?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I added console logs and both methods are being called on page load and when I return to the component.

Comment: so back is the back button on browser or the Link to go to the previous page

Comment: I click a <link> in my header which loads a different component. I then click a different <link<> in my header which reloads the component above.

Comment: and is the width of the component 0% or 70% after you click back

Comment: Is Link a custom component or something from a router library? If so, does that library track & restore the state?

Comment: It's stuck at 70% after that first load, it never resets when you return to the component on browser navigation

Comment: @veratti I'm using react router 4, `import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';`

Comment: the render method must be getting cached, I'm not sure how to fix that

Comment: do one thing  in componentDidMount try, `setTimeout(() => { this.setState({
      measureCompletion: '70%',
    });}, 3000)`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that made it work but is a setTimeout the right way with React to do this?

Comment: So What I think was happening is that, the transition from 0% to 70% width was so quick on reload that it was not visible, so a delay in making that transition helps

Comment: the transition takes a while so I think it's more react has some caching going on and things the results of render() have not changed...

Comment: you can be sure of that by having console.log(this.state.measureCompletion) in the render, if you get 0% intially and 70% later than this is not the case

Comment: Render does show 0 and then 70 but maybe react is using the output idk

Comment: You could introduce the animation delay in the CSS instead of a timeout in JavaScript, though I'm not totally sure that there isn't another solution. Your DidMount is calling, so the component is being remounted. However, if just a query Parma is changing in your route, could it be possible that this child component is just being changed from the DOM's perspective (instead of fully recreated)? Maybe try adding a key to force the element to be treated as new to see if that has any effect?

Comment: -- a key that is unique per mount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by a couple of reasons that I can think of off the top of my head. When you say 'navigating' and I see that you are using react-router, so I am assuming you are going to a link and back.

Now the reason your state is the same when you navigate back to your component is that it never dismounted. React router **updates** components by passing down routing props. Check out the documentation from the [ReactTraining](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component) site.

Since your component is already mounted and will be receiving new props from React Router this might be a good time to check out [**componentWillReceiveProps**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops).

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in this method.

Once you have reset your state back to 0 to initiate the animation you can then use **componentDidUpdate** to trigger the css animation.